# Systemjs configuration Error in javascript and html

Tags: systemjs

I want to use modules in my javascript and html. When i use systemjs with version 5, i am getting error, in github i cant see the steps to configuration. If i removed System.config from below code, at that time i getting CORS issue.

1. What are the package i have to use to run modules in javascript and html
2. How to set the configurations for latest version

   ```
           <!-- <script src="node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur.js"></script>
           <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist//system.js"></script> -->
           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/5.0.0/system.js"></script>
       </head>

       <body>
           <script>
   //Configuration 
               System.config({
                   'meta': {
                       './js/*.js': {
                           format: 'esm'
                       }
                   }
               });
               System.import('./js/app.js');
           </script>
   ```

   ```
       I am getting Error : index.html:18 Uncaught TypeError: System.config is not a function. if I removed system.config i am getting Error : Unable to resolve bare specifier "js/app.js" from file:///C:/Train/ES6/systemjss/ at throwBare (system.js:184)     at resolveImportMap (system.js:180)     at system.js:734
   ```